# Ionic Ajustar imagen e icono

Tags: html, css, ionic

Buen día, quisiera saber como logro que en la siguiente imagen, el icono se ponga encima de la imagen.

Este es lo que tengo por ahora.

HTML

```
<ion-row responsive-sm>
      <ion-col col-12 width-50 text-center>
        <img class="user-avatar round" style="height: auto; max-width: 23vh;" [src]="chosenPicture || placeholder"
          onerror="this.src='../../assets/imgs/avatar.png'">

        <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

CSS

```
.user-avatar {
    max-width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    padding: .5em;
    height: 12vh;
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 4px 4px #444);
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero que se muestre y con el mismo estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Copia el codigo tal cual lo tenes ahora asi es mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código fuente de la muestra.